# Proguard: IllegalArgumentException - is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, rules

**Help me, please!**

I have been trying to overcome this problem and seeing various solutions by placing any of the following rules, it still does not work:

> -optimizations !method/removal/parameter
>
> -optimizations !class/unboxing/enum

If I put the following rule it works, but I don't fully understand its functionality and I doubt its use:

> -dontoptimize

This is the error I get

```
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [com/test/proyect/recognizers/documents/UsdlFrontDocument]
  Method      = [buildResponseData()Lcom/test/proyect/recognizers/ResponseData;]
  Instruction = [18] ificmpeq +5 (target=23)
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "com/microblink/entities/recognizers/Recognizer$Result$State?" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue])
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/test/proyect/recognizers/documents/UsdlFrontDocument]
  Method      = [buildResponseData()Lcom/test/proyect/recognizers/ResponseData;]

  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "com/microblink/entities/recognizers/Recognizer$Result$State?" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue])
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to optimize an already optimized code, which does not need further optimizations and possibly causes some bug in ProGuard. Is there a sample project/app which can be used for reproducing the issue?

Comment: @DoDo not at the moment, since this error came out in a new project

Comment: Can you please create something where we can reproduce this problem? Disclaimer: we’re from the Microblink team.